# How to substitute a global variable for multiple triggers on cloud build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Cloud build allows user-defined substitutions for the single trigger, But I need to assign global user-defined substitutions variable for multiple triggers.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question well, you are asking about sharing user-defined substituting variable values across different Cloud Build builds.

This is not currently possible since the [user-defined substitutions](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions) are related to an specific build either by being specified in the `cloudbuild.yaml` config file or in the [`--substitutions argument`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--substitutions) flag for the `gcloud` command.

Answer (score 0):

If the substitution is about environment variables which remains fairly constant across the triggers like project id or location, you can use 'substitution: build.projectId'

Likewise for other env variables.

Comment: I'm not getting it.

Comment: Substitution variables must begin with an underscore (_) and use only uppercase letters and numbers, or be one of the following: REPO_NAME, BRANCH_NAME, TAG_NAME, REVISION_ID, COMMIT_SHA, SHORT_SHA